# Remove full file path from text using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to clean up some textual data to train a LDA topic model on them, but some datapoints include file paths. How can I remove them effectively using a regex?
For example:

Input:

> This is a sample text containing a file path: C:\Users\Username\Documents\file.txt. This is another path: D:\Data\folder\file.docx .

Desired output:

> This is a sample text containing a file path: . This is another path:  .

Thanks for you time!

Comment: What language are you using? And can your paths contain spaces? Can they lack extensions? If yes, there is literally no way to automatically decide what parts of `This is a text with a c:\path\to some file`  are actually belonging to the path or to the surrounding text.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Seems I have an answer but provide your attempt(s) first)

Comment: @Slava depending on what can or cannot be part of OP's path, the answer can be anything from trivial to impossible. But without further details nobody can say which it really is

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

This one will require the file-extension.

```
[A-Z]:\\.*?\.[^\s]+(?<!\.)
```

And this one doesn't.

```
[A-Z]:\\.*?(?:[^\s]+|(?:\.[^\s]+(?<!\.))?)
```

These will return the following, if the matches are removed.

```
This is a sample text containing a file path: . This is another path:  .
```